# How to install GDAL with TIFF support on Linux?

Tags: gdal, installation

I am trying to install GDAL on a linux machine and tested some sample commands like `gdalinfo --version` This worked fine, but when I started working with images like `.tif` I got the following error .

```
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectoryCheckOrder:Invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order
ERROR 1: MissingRequired:TIFF directory is missing required "ImageLength" field
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '1.tif'.
```

I reinstalled `libtiff` but I am still getting the same error.

Iam working on CentOS release 5.7 (Final) .Is there any one who worked on this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of GDAL are you using and what exact command and file gave you that error?

Answer (score 4):

Are you installing from source?  You might try --with-libtiff=internal and --with-geotiff=internal to have GDAL use its own sources for these libraries rather than depend on system libraries which are likely to be old.

Comment: I tried the one you have suggested                             wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/gdal-1.9.0.tar.gz                                                   tar -zxvf gdal-1.9.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 3):

Just for diagnosis, on my ubuntu linux box I'd do this:

Run

```
ldd `which gdalinfo`
```

you'll see that the gdalinfo itself does not dynamically load libtiff4:

```
ldd `which gdalinfo` | grep -i tif  #shows nothing
```

What happens if you ran this:

```
gdalinfo --debug on 1.tif
```

My output

```
GDAL: GDALOpen(1.tif, this=0x8d6c70) succeeds as GTiff.
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
...
```

Often it helps to install  libtiff4-dev package as well.